# Error: Server terminated unexpectedly with code: null signal: SIGTERM

Tags: reactjs, react-starter-kit

```
> @ start C:\mohan\experiments\react\boilerplates\MyApp

babel-node tools/run start
[12:12:57] Starting 'start'...
[12:12:57] Starting 'clean'...
[12:12:58] Finished 'clean' after 49 ms
[12:12:58] Starting 'bound copy'...
[12:12:58] Finished 'bound copy' after 162 ms
webpack built 869f3b2ac4a25f52f21e in 9500ms
Child
Time: 9500ms
Asset Size Chunks Chunk Names
main.js?869f3b2ac4a25f52f21e 4.19 MB 0 [emitted] main
Child
Time: 8319ms
Asset Size Chunks Chunk Names
../../server.js 197 kB 0 [emitted] main
../../server.js.map 213 kB 0 [emitted] main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
webpack: bundle is now INVALID.
webpack building...
webpack built 869f3b2ac4a25f52f21e in 502ms
Child
Time: 502ms
Child
Time: 8319ms
Asset Size Chunks Chunk Names
../../server.js 197 kB 0 [emitted] main
../../server.js.map 213 kB 0 [emitted] main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
C:\mohan\experiments\react\boilerplates\MyApp\tools\runServer.js:71
throw new Error(`Server terminated unexpectedly with code: ${ cod
^

Error: Server terminated unexpectedly with code: null signal: SIGTERM
at ChildProcess.server.once (runServer.js:53:15)
at ChildProcess.g (events.js:286:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\n
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ start: babel-node tools/run start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script 'babel-node tools/run start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm install
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! babel-node tools/run start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
npm ERR! npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\mohan\experiments\react\boilerplates\MyApp\npm-debug.log
```

I am new to react starter kit. Following things i have done

1. git clone -o react-starter-kit -b master --single-branch
   https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit.git MyApp
2. npm install
3. npm start [Hed this issue]

Please help.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this temporarily by commenting out lines 51 to 57 in tools/sunServer.js.  like this:

```
// if (pending) {
//   server.once('exit', (code, signal) => {
//     if (pending) {
//       throw new Error(`Server terminated unexpectedly with code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);
//     }
//   });
// }
```

That will solve the problem and let you get back to work,  however I am not sure of the actual root cause of the problem.

Comment: This wont solve the problem, since both vendor.js and client.js wont be generated.

Comment: @juancancela they seem to generate fine,  can you elaborate?